# Cannot find 'describe' on npm run build

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

React with RCA and TS

I am getting this error when I try to run `npm run build`

```
Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha
```

Almost everything related with test has error on build. I've checked in node_modules and is true that those types aren't there.

This problem does not happen when I am in dev mode, everything works fine, all tests have passed. The issue it's on deployment with run build.

I've already installed @types/jest and @types/testing-library, also I´ve tried to push "jest" into array types in tsconfig.json and I checked that tsconfig includes my tests folder.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me?

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/analytics-browser": "^1.1.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^1.3.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "antd": "^4.21.6",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "enquire-js": "^0.2.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "gerador-validador-cpf": "^5.0.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.2.6",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "npm": "^8.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.4",
    "react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^2.2.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "recharts": "^2.1.10",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -e development react-scripts start",
    "build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true env-cmd -e production react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --maxWorkers=50% --passWithNoTests",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src --max-warnings=0",
    "build:test": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true env-cmd -e test react-scripts build",
    "generate": "yarn plop --plopfile generators/plopfile.js",
    "typecheck": "tsc --project tsconfig.json --noEmit"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*": [
      "npm test --findRelatedTests --bail"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.15",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-addons-linked-state-mixin": "^0.14.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.7",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.23",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "msw": "^0.47.3",
    "plop": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

UPDATE: If i put all the packages that are getting error in dependencies, it works fine. Of course this isn´t a good solution!

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: Yes, i am using TypeScript

Comment: Could you share the full code of package.json and tsconfig?

Comment: Yes, i made the update

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using TypeScript
From the [Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api) it appears that the the global functions need to be explicitly imported.

`describe` is one of these global functions so will need the explicit import

[image: Screenshot from docs]

Comment: It changes a lot, ty. Now I am getting an error on @testing-library/react. But I think I should use this setup too: [link](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup). Do you have any of what happend, because on npm run start works fine.

Comment: I believe it may have something to do with how it is transpiled? I think `npm run` all the global testing functions are accessible, but when TS is transpiled, it loses it's ability to "find" those global functions. Hence the added steps on the link you sent. Looks like further `tsconfig` changes are needed [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#:~:text=If%20you%27re%20using%20TypeScript%2C%20merge%20this%20into%20your%20tsconfig.json.%C2%A0If%20you%27re%20using%20Create%20React%20App%20without%20TypeScript%2C%20save%20this%20to%20jsconfig.json%20instead.)?

Comment: But this case happen when the project has a custom Setup, i don´t have any custom setup and I'm getting this error.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation feels that using TypeScript _is_ a form of customisation?

Comment: Even if I create the custom file to render, i still get the error about: `Cannot find module '@testing-library/react' or its corresponding type declarations`